# ObjectOutputStream in Java

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I have a function

```
public void loadUserOnline() {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(req); //Send request to Server to get online users
            oos.flush();
            LinkedList<UserOnlineInfo> userOnlineInfoList = (LinkedList<UserOnlineInfo>)ois.readObject(); // read object from Server contains online users
            Vector<String> listData = new Vector<>(); // a Vector for JList
            for (int i = 0; i < userOnlineInfoList.size(); i++) {
                listData.add(userOnlineInfoList.get(i).getUser() + " --- " + userOnlineInfoList.get(i).getStatus()); // add elements to Vector
            }
            theList.setListData(listData); // set data source for JList
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The first time I call this function, it gets data from a server. Then data from the server changes. I call this function a second time, and the data is the same as the first time. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` every time you want to resend the same object with new values, or else use `writeUnshared()`. See the Javadoc.

Comment: I try to call ObjectOutputStream.reset() and it works. Thanks you @EJP

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same ObjectOutputStream instance, `oos`, which has been exhausted by the first call to this method. If you initialise your ObjectOutputStream again then you'll get a new stream:

```
public void loadUserOnline() {
   // initialise oos here or before the call to this method
   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(...... 
   try {
      oos.writeObject(req);
....
```

Comment: There is no such thing as 'exhausting' an ObjectOutputStream, and the suggested solution only works if the peer also uses a new ObjectInputStream at exactly the same moment, which is rather difficult to organise and also slightly inefficient due to the space overhead. Otherwise the reader gets StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code AC. -1.